# Securely store password in database and then show it on demand?

Tags: php, security

I have written a small password manager script for my own purposes. It is hosted locally and cannot be accessed outside my local network. You can see the code on [GutHub](https://github.com/milenmk/Simple-Password-Manager)

I know it is better to encrypt the passwords before storing them in the database, but how to retrieve them back when viewing the record? I mean I don't need to verify the password but see it's actual value.

There are some options, but they all require a "key" or "salt" that will be hardcoded in the files and can be viewed by anyone. One that I though to use is this:

```
// Store the cipher method
$ciphering = 'AES-128-CTR';

// Use OpenSSl Encryption method
$iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($ciphering);
$options = 0; # the AES options

// Non-NULL Initialization Vector for encryption
$encryption_iv = '4828992577348297';

// Store the encryption key
$encryption_key = 'tEDo5MHxsqiq6dtXgr7za8EzhXuQqG';

$this->pass_crypted = openssl_encrypt($this->password, $ciphering, $encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv);
```

I am thinking of putting `$encryption_iv` and `$encryption_key` in a file outside the "project" folder and including the file when needed. Are there any other ways?

Comment: Code Review requires concrete code from a project. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any other ways?

You can derive your key and IV using the PBKDF2 password-based key hashing algorithm. This algorithm is supported by PHP.

There's even an entire specification dedicated to it: [PKCS #5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8018/)

The usual warnings about implementing/using cryptography in your projects apply: Don't roll your own crypto - This means don't design your own cryptographic scheme, don't implement a specification without understanding any and all potential pitfalls of **MIS**-implemmenting them.